# How to automate changing old password

Tags: password

To change the password, I can run the following

```
echo "user:$npasswd" | chpasswd.
```

...but after executing this it asks me to enter the current password.

Is there a way to automatically provide it with the current password?

Answer (score 5):

as a user:

```
$ echo "rinzwind:2" | chpasswd
Changing password for rinzwind.
chpasswd: (user rinzwind) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 1, user rinzwind) password not changed
```

as root:

```
root@schijfwereld:~# echo "rinzwind:1" | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
root@schijfwereld:~#
```

You need to do it as "root". ANY other method of course will ask for the current password. It would be a security issue if you could alter it

When you do it as "root" it also accepts short passwords as you can see. Setting "1" as a password is not allowed by default from a normal prompt.

You can do

```
$ echo -e "1\naaaabbbb\naaaabbbb" | passwd rinzwind
```

where 1 is the old password and aaaabbbb is the new password. The flow of passwd is: old password, enter, new password, enter, new password. Mind that the password is visible (if only for a brief moment) in the processlist.

Comment: Thanks so much after your comment at least I know as a root I need no to give password but it create smiliar question since to switch to root account I need type sudo -i command .for that as well it's ask current password . How to provide current password through script

Comment: You may also mention that the `\n` between the old password and the new password, and again between the new password and new password significant line breaks.

Comment: @user68186 good call :) :)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for valuable feedback . For echo -e command is there a way to send password through command line like below. echo -e "$2\n$3\n$3" | passwd $1.  Where $1 is username and $2 and $3 is old and new password respectivly

Comment: I am new to script please help for code in script